# Add class to div when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a class to be added to a div element when clicked. I can not get it to work, I have it set up similar to this:

javascript:

```
function choose() {
    this.addClass("selected");
}
```

html:

```
<div class="initialclass" onclick="choose()">CLICK</div>
```

I have other javascript commands in that function that are working properly I just can't get the class to add.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have two issues with your current code. First is that `this` in your JS function refers to the `window`, not the element that was clicked. Second if it did refer to that element, it would be a DOMElement, not a jQuery object, so it would not have the `addClass()` method - you need to convert it to a jQuery object. Try this:

```
<div class="initialclass" onclick="choose(this)">CLICK</div>
```

```js
function choose(el) {
    $(el).addClass("selected");
}
```

Note however, that it is better practice to hook up your events using JavaScript. As you are using jQuery, you can do this:

```
<div class="initialclass">CLICK</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('.initialclass').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
});
```

Comment: What are the reasons for option 1?

Answer (score 2):

change your html like this:-

```
<div class="initialclass" onclick="choose(this)">CLICK</div>
```

and function:-

```
function choose(dv) {
   $(dv).addClass("selected");
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList):

> classList returns a token list of the class attribute of the element.

```
el.classList.add("selected");
```

`classList.add`:

> Adds a class to an element's list of classes. If class already exists in the element's list of classes, it will not add the class again.

**CODE**

HTML:

```
<div class="initialclass" onclick="choose(this)">CLICK</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function choose(el) {
    el.classList.add("selected");
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/kcpxwng4/)

Answer (score 1):

If you use jquery add this is code in your `$(document).ready()`

```
$(".initialclass").click(function(){
   $(this).addClass("selected");

});
```

Comment: I kinda wanted it to be in the onclick function since there are some inputs that are element specific for the other actions that the function completes but I guess it really doesn't all need to be together. THANKS!!!