# Click On window to add class on span

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can remove class when I click On button. I need To add the remove class again after I click on button and span display when I click On window

my HTML file

```
<button>Click To show Comment</button>
<span class="my_comment my_comment_none">Hello</span>
```

my CSS FILE

```
.my_comment{display: block} .my_comment_none{display: none}
```

my js File

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("button").click(function () {
      $(this).removeClass("my_comment_none");
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add class to div when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141650/add-class-to-div-when-clicked)

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
   $("button").toggle(function () {
      $(this).toggleClass("my_comment_none");
    });
});

Comment: use $(this).toggleClass("my_coment_none");

Answer (score 2):

You can attach the click event on `document` object and check the target name to hide or show the comment:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).click(function (e) {
      if($(e.target).is('BUTTON'))
        $('.my_comment').show();   
      else
        $('.my_comment').hide();
    });
});
```

```css
.my_comment{display: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div>Click on the button to show the comment 
  and hide the comment on clicking anywhere else</div>
  <button>Click To show Comment</button>
<span class="my_comment" id="comment">Hello</span>
```

Comment: I just need on click on window not button

Comment: oh man, I need on click on button the class my_comment_none remove and return add the class again on click on window

Comment: @MohamedSamy, if the answer solves your problem then you can accept the answer by click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.....thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use toggleClass

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("my_comment_none");
        });
    });
```

for window click . maintain any unique id for button and use selectors with id

```
$(window).click(function () {
    if ($('button').hasClass("my_comment_none")) {
        $('button').removeClass("my_comment_none");
    }
})
```

;

Comment: I just need on click on window not button

Answer (score 0):

use toggleClass

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("button").click(function () {
          $(this).toggleClass("my_comment_none");
        });
    });
```

Comment: I just need on click on window not button

Answer (score 0):

You may use simply jQuery slideToggle() function.

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $(".toggle").slideToggle();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click To hide/show</button>
<div class="toggle">Hello</div>
```